# Socket option SO_RCVTIMEO inaccurate?

Tags: c++, timeout, setsockopt

I use hiredis redisSetTimeout function set timeout 10ms, when i start 100 thread it is accurate 10ms, but when i start 1000 thread, some call in redisVCommand cost 300+ms, and not timeout, can anyone explain this in detail?

redisSetTimeout function call the following system function

```
setsockopt(c->fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,&tv,sizeof(tv))  
setsockopt(c->fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDTIMEO,&tv,sizeof(tv))
```

Comment: Nobody said it was accurate to any specific degree. If you have a busy system, threads may not get scheduled for an appreciable time after their sleeps or timeouts expire. A 10ms select timeout is wildly optimistic. Most people use multiples of seconds. Maybe *increasing* your timeout would reduce your latencies. Think about it.

Comment: in production environment， I set timeout 100ms, it can delay to 40s or even more.